# git command hangs in cmd

Tags: windows, git

I tried to run `git` and `git --version`, they all hang and never exit back to prompt
for example, git version hangs after prints the version info like this, I can't even use ctrl+c to terminate it.

```
C:\Users\dummyhead>git --version
git version 2.28.0.windows.1
```

I tried portable version, 32bit and 64bit git pacakge, and even the git comes with visual studio 2019, they all behave the same.

Comment: Is this a new problem for you? Is it a large or small repo? Try running `git gc`.

Comment: it is very small, i think it is new, as i usually use vs2019 to commit and sync, recently i tried to add submodule, and find out i couldn't run any git.

Comment: i found out that after i rebooted the machine, i could run git --version successfully once, and only once, if i tried to executed git --version again in the same command console, it stuck again after print version info.

Comment: Does this happen only in cmd ? or in other shells as well (`git-bash`, `powershell`) ?

Comment: i tried powershell as well, it behaved the same problem.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out what was the problem? Got the same issue now, but with `commit`, `push` and `pull`.